# Where are other important fonts in google docs font list?

Tags: google-docs, font

I can see that there is not `Tahoma` font in the document that I am currently working on.

How should add it, please?

Answer (score 4):

In the font selector, at the bottom, is a link to "*Add fonts...*". Click that.

[image: "Add fonts..." link]

The "Add fonts" tool will open, showing all available fonts and indicating which ones you're using.

[image: "Add fonts" tool]

Simply find Tahoma (or whatever font you're looking for)...

[image: search for font]

...and click it so that there is a checkmark next to it. Click OK.

[image: selected font]

And now you should see Tahoma in your list of fonts while editing your document.

[image: newly added font in list of fonts]

Comment: I should really thank for the great and complete answer, but I should also mention that I cannot see the option `Add Fonts...` at the end of the font list. Can it be because I have created the document from an attachment in an email received? The attachment was a `.doc` file. I have ubuntu and Chromium. Whenever I wanted to take a shot (no matter using `Awesome Screenshot` nor keyboard's `Print Screen` button), the font list was gone.

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue. Did you convert the document to Google Docs format, or are you just using the viewer? I created the screen shots using Firefox on Windows, but I don't see anything on the [Google blog about fonts](http://googledocs.blogspot.com/2012/05/april-in-review-new-fonts-galore-and.html) that mentions anything about a browser and/or OS limitation.